# Problems closing mobile menu with toggleClass

Tags: jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu, menu, toggleclass

I am trying to resolve an issue with a mobile menu.  This is not a website that I created, so I am a little unfamiliar with the developer's code.  I thought the problem should be an easy enough fix, but I can't quite nail it.  Basically, when you click on the Main Menu button, a dropdown menu appears.  It stays up until you click on main menu a second time.  I would ideally like to have the menu close whenever one of the other pages in the menu is clicked.  In other words, clicking menu opens the dropdown menu, and then clicking 'home' or 'about' would make the menu disappear.

I am unfortunately not able to supply a web link or the actual files.  I tried to create a fiddle, but couldn't get it to work.  I am a little new to this, so I apologize.  If you are not able to help me, I understand.  I am really just looking for some suggestions to try.

That said, here is a rough sketch of the html I am working with:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="menu main-menu”>
    <span class="menu-switch">MAIN MENU</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=“#home”>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=“#about”>About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=“#contact”>Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

A toggleClass function is being used to switch the menu off and on.

```
$('span.menu-switch' ).click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
```

The 'open' class refers to CSS styles for the dropdown.

I have tried applying a toggleClass on the other, various pages, like so:

```
$('li a#home' ).click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
```

My reasoning was that clicking toggleClass a second time on one of the other page links would remove the 'open' class and thereby close the menu.  I have tried variations on this, such as playing with different selectors, but nothing seems to work for me.  Please let me know if I can supply any other helpful information.  I appreciate any constructive suggestions.  Thank you very much for your time.

PROBLEM SOLVED.  I got it to work like this:

```
$('li a').on('click', function() {
       $('span.menu-switch').removeClass('open');
    });
```

Comment: Problem solved.  I got it to work like this:

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="menu"></span>
            <div class="top-menu">
                <ul>                                           
                    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Naslovna</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cenovnik.html">Cenovnik</a></li>
                    <li><a href="usluga.html">Usluge</a></li>
                    <li><a href="prijatelji.html">Prijatelji</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://potrcko.net/magazin">Magazin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://potrcko.net/kuvar">Kuvar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- script for menu -->
            <script>
            $( "span.menu" ).click(function(event) {
              $( ".top-menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
            });
        </script>
```